# Json autocomplete not working properly

Tags: php, json, jquery-ui, jquery

So im trying to populate an auto-complete search form from my database. Here is my php code that creates an array

```
    $leaders= mysql_query("SELECT model_name,model_id FROM models
             ORDER by model_name DESC");

while($leader=mysql_fetch_array($leaders)){
  $model= $leader['model_name'];
$modelid= $leader['model_id'];
    $name[] = array('label'=> $model, 'value'=> $modelid);

    $count = $count + 1;


}
$fp = fopen('results.php', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($name));
fclose($fp);
```

My problem lies somewhere within the jquery auto complete, the search form just returns a huge list of all the products in my json without filtering when the user types. My ideal goal would be to assign the value to the end of a url. Ex. "http://www.example.com/" + value

```
$(function() {
  $("#search").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "results.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { q: request.term },
        success: function(data) {
          response($.map(data, function(value,key) {
            return { label:value.label , value: value.value }
          }));
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 2
  });
});
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Is there any actual filtering code? You could put a `LIMIT` on your SQL query.

Comment: Why are you writing to a different `.php` file? why not just `echo json_encode(..` directly?

Comment: When you use a server-side data source *you* are responsible for doing the filtering. The autocomplete widget is just displaying the results.

Comment: theres a few thousand products, so i dont want to slow the load time of the page. Can you possibly point me in the right direction on how i can get this to work?

Comment: MMK's answer is a good starting point, you can handle what's sent by JQuery's Autocomplete's Ajax request with `$_POST['term']`. And about your response to writing to a different `.php` file.. WHAT?!

Comment: Im a little confused, what would i have to do to fill and auto complete form with http://mogulcases.com/matt/results.php

Comment: Don't you have it working except for the filtering? If you want to load all of the possible autocomplete candidates and them have the browser filter them, that's an option too, however I would recommend doing the filtering on the server if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your query was worng. you must use like condition on your query

```
 mysql_query("SELECT model_name,model_id FROM models where model_name like '$_post[q]%'  ORDER by model_name DESC")
```

to fetch the particular selected result

Answer (score 0):

As stated by arxanas it looks as though you need to filter the results before you encode them and send them back to the client-side.

One example of this could be to first catch the term the jquery autocomplete sends to the server like so

```
$term = $_GET['term'];
```

then use this to compare against your name array, I think if you turned term into a pattern like so

```
$term = "/$term/i"
```

and then created an array to store your matched results and looped over names array using preg_match, everytime the pattern is matched you just push it the value into the return array

```
$returnArray = array();

foreach( $name as $index => $value ) {
    if ( preg_match( $term, $value['label'] ) {
        array_push($returnArray, $value);
    };
};

return json_encode($returnArray);
```

Like I say, I think this will work, but preg_match is pretty slow and i've not tested it myself so good luck!